# Uso de botones y funciones

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa que dados los números naturales a, b y n, me devuelva los n números de la forma a+b*n. Por ejemplo, si escribo 2, 3 y 4 el programa me devuelve la lista [2,5,8,11]. No tuve problemas para escribir el código en Python, es éste:

```
a = int(input("a= "))
b = int(input("b= "))
n = int(input("#: "))

lista = []
for n in range(n):
    num = a+b*n
    lista.append(num)

print("N(", a, ",", b, ") =", lista)
```

El problema es que cuando quiero crear una interfaz con botones, no sé cómo "poner" la lista dentro de la función. Como no sé nada de programación, tomé un código que vi en Youtube para hacer una calculadora y lo retoqué así, pero no funciona:

```
from tkinter import *

def sumar():
    lista = []
    for vartxt3 in range(vartxt3):
        num = vartxt1 + vartxt2 * vartxt3
        lista.append(num)
    varres.set("suma = " + str(lista))

def limpiar():
    varres.set("")
    vartxt1.set("")
    vartxt2.set("")
    vartxt3.set("")

ventana = Frame(height=170, width=360)
ventana.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

vartxt1 = StringVar()
txt1 = Entry(ventana, textvariable=vartxt1).place(x=0, y=0)

vartxt2 = StringVar()
txt2 = Entry(ventana, textvariable=vartxt2).place(x=130, y=0)

vartxt3 = StringVar()
txt3 = Entry(ventana, textvariable=vartxt3).place(x=260, y=0)


varres = StringVar()
txtres = Entry(ventana, textvariable=varres, width=100).place(x=0, y=145)


bsum = Button(ventana, command=sumar, text="Sumar", padx=42, pady=5).place(x=0, y=25)
blim = Button(ventana, command=limpiar, text="Limpiar", padx=42, pady=5).place(x=60, y=100)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Bueno, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Podrías poner el código como texto por favor? Ten en cuenta que, además de que muchos no tenemos ganas (ni, quizas, tiempo) de transcribir tu código, existen otros motivos enumerados en [una respuesta en meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880).

Comment: Sí, sí, perdón, soy nuevo y no sabía cómo indentar, por eso había puesto la captura de pantalla... Gracias,

Comment: El código tiene errores en tiempo de ejecución (`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'vartxt3' referenced before assignment`).

Comment: Sí... la pregunta es cómo puedo solucionarlo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ahí esta resuelto solo tenias que traer el valor de tus IntVar() con .get()

```py
from tkinter import *

def sumar():
    lista = []
    num = 0
    print()
    for n in range(vartxt3.get()):
        num = vartxt1.get() + vartxt2.get() *n
        lista.append(num)
    varres.set("suma = " + str(lista))

def limpiar():
    varres.set("")
    vartxt1.set("")
    vartxt2.set("")
    vartxt3.set("")

ventana = Frame(height=170, width=360)
ventana.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

vartxt1 = IntVar()
txt1 = Entry(ventana, textvariable=vartxt1).place(x=0, y=0)

vartxt2 = IntVar()
txt2 = Entry(ventana, textvariable=vartxt2).place(x=130, y=0)

vartxt3 = IntVar()
txt3 = Entry(ventana, textvariable=vartxt3).place(x=260, y=0)


varres = StringVar()
txtres = Entry(ventana, textvariable=varres, width=100).place(x=0, y=145)


bsum = Button(ventana, command=sumar, text="Sumar", padx=42, pady=5).place(x=0, y=25)
blim = Button(ventana, command=limpiar, text="Limpiar", padx=42, pady=5).place(x=60, y=100)

ventana.mainloop()
```

> resultado
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡ESPECTACULAR! ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: si te sirvió dale +1

Comment: @JoséValentín corrección, si la respuesta soluciona el problema entonces debe marcarse como aceptada.

Comment: Sí, sí... recién me di cuenta... Ya la marqué como aceptada. Muchas gracias.